# Render RABL partials with polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I have a data model where a `User` can like a `Project, Suggestion, Comment`, or other objects.
The models are set up correctly, and `likes/show.rabl` works if we were just to support the `Project` child

```
object @like
attributes :id, :created_at, :target_type, :target_id, :user_id
child :user => :user do
  extends "users/show"
end
child :target do
  node do |project|
    partial('projects/show', :object => project)
  end
end
```

However, I want to be able to use partials of `suggestions/show, comments/show` as well depending on `target_type`.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
child :target do |u|
  u.target.map do |r|
    if r.is_a?(Suggestion)
      partial("suggestions/show", :object => r)
    elsif r.is_a?(Project)
      partial("projects/show", :object => r)
    end
  end
end
```

I get `undefined method target for <Rabl::Engine:0x69fb988>`. However, I don't get this error in the first case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `extends` instead of `partial`?

Perhaps you could try something like this?

```
child :target do |u|
  u.target.map do |r|
    if r.is_a?(Suggestion)
      extends "suggestions/show"
    elsif r.is_a?(Project)
      extends "projects/show"
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, when you use `extends`, you don't need to pass in an `:object` because you're already in the scope of iterating through with the object `r`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up using and it worked.

Thanks to this post: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/273#issuecomment-6580713

```
child :target do
  node do |r|
    if r.is_a?(Suggestion)
      partial("suggestions/show", :object => r)
    elsif r.is_a?(Project)
      partial("projects/show", :object => r)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this, where you do not have to list all possible polymorphic relations. It may be a bit hacky, but it works.

Like this:

```
child :target do |u|
  # The regexp snippet selects everything from the last / and to the end
  extends u.to_partial_path.gsub(/\/([^\/]+)$/, '/show')
end
```

This uses the `.to_partial_path` of your object. If your object is called `Suggestion`, the `.to_partial_path` will return `suggestions/suggestion`. This is why i'm using `gsub()` to replace whatever comes after `/` with `/show`.

With this solution you do not have to update this file each time you add another polymorphic relation. You only have to make sure that the new object has a rabl template called `show.json.rabl`